# CreateFile() not working in Qt Creator?

Tags: c, qt, winapi

At my learning place (Visual Studio 2008, Windows 7 x64) I started a little program. It works there. 
On my freetime laptop I have only Qt Creator 5.2, Windows 8.1. I wanted to test something so I tried to edit the source code on my laptop.
It builds with no errors, but I'm having problems with this part:

```
    HANDLE hFile;
    hFile = CreateFile(argv[1],
        GENERIC_READ,
        FILE_SHARE_READ,
        NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
        NULL);

    if(hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){
        printf("Could not open file.\n");
    }
```

It never opens the file. I verified if argv[1] has the file name. I tried with a file from the current folder, I tried with the full path, I tried with Administrator rights, I even tried compatibility mode - still the same. I only took my code with me when I left, so I can't try with the .exe that works.

What am I loosing here?

GetLastError() returns The system cannot find the file specified. Which is hard to accept when everything has a simple name and path (so I can be sure I didn't typed something wrong).

In Qt I made a new Non Qt - Plain C Project.

Comment: GetLastError() doesn't lie. Something else is going on.

Comment: What compiler are you using in your freetime laptop?

Comment: @bruno.karklis MinGW 4.8.1

Comment: I know that is windows.h only work with microsoft compilers and CreateFile is a windows function from windows.h ...

Comment: Try to check is mingw is loading and using windows.h. increase the level of warning.

Comment: Someplaces use a layer tthat translate windows.h functions to other compiller like gcc

Comment: I think your mingw need windows SDK

Comment: Windows already told you the answer. The file does not exist.

Comment: @bruno.karklis I was thinking about the same thing (I wasn't expecting it to build, but I tried anyway), but it's weird how there are no errors or warnings. This isn't the machine on which I intended to work on this project so it was more a curiosity than a problem.

Comment: For curiosity is important to increase the levels of warnings because this will help to undertend things, if level is not  correcly placed the problem will be hide

Comment: I suspect that the current working directory is not what you expect.   If you specify a full path name, does it work?

Comment: What @bruno.karklis is just not true. You can certainly call Win32 API functions from all sorts of compilers other than the MS compilers. There's no need for layers and mapping or anything like this. The problem would appear to be nothing more than `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` as `GetLastError` says. Very hard to see beyond that.

Comment: Manually calling CreateFileA works.

Answer (score 1):

You're not providing an absolute path of the file to your program, or your assumption of the current working directory is wrong. This is a classic, and this question has nothing to do with Qt.

Remember: unless you're running it from the commandline *yourself*, you simply can't know what the working directory is. So you need to pass any file arguments as absolute paths.

Comment: I run it from the command line, that's the way I want it to work.